# how to align action bar title (with search view, but no home icon) closer to left

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

Having a actionbar with searchView. 
The actionbar itself does not have home icon and "up" indicator (the one left to the home icon).
But the search view has custom "up" indicator icon.

like when searchView is collapsed (o for searchIcon here):

```
   Title------------------O otherMenuItem
```

When expand the searchView (< is the "up" indicator):

```
 < search term________________ x
```

so in the theme style, it has android:homeAsUpIndicator for closing the expanded searchView with custom "up" indicator icon, (there is getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_action_back); for api > 18, but seems the searchView only recognize the one defined in the theme, and have to cover pre-18 anyway, so setHomeAsUpIndicator is not the solution):

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/icon_action_back</item>
```

and in onCreate() did:

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);// to not show the "up" indicator when searchView is collapsed
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);

    ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)); 
    drawable.setBounds(0,0,0,0); 
    getActionBar().setIcon(drawable);//prevent home icon take space

    getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

When the searchView is expanded the "up" indicator is shown automatically, without call

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

When the searchView is collapsed, in the left of the actionbar before the title there is always space with the width of the custom icon defined in <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/icon_action_back</item>

How to remove this space to align the title closer to the window's left?

Searched around and find some solution to hack with id, seems it not a right way to rely on the internal ids.

Anyone happen to solve this problem before? Or if it has to use custom action bar with searchView?
Thanks!